# How can I store and filter large JSON objects (above 70,000)?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, es6-promise

```
const users = [
    {id:1, email:"abc@email.com"},
    {id:2, email:"xyz@email.com"},
    {....}(~70,000 objects)
]

function a(){
    const id = 545
    users.filter((value)=>{
        if(value.id === id)
            return true
    })
}
```

We have 70,000 users' objects. we need to filter the email based on the id.

users= [{id: '1001', email: "abc@gmail.com"}, {{id: '1002', email: "spc@gmail.com"} , ..];

Using array and array.filter() ends up in the error.
Error
[image]

what's the best way of approach for this?

Comment: Please add error details ***to the text*** of this question so that others who encounter the same issue will be able to search for this question.

Comment: Use a database.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be best to convert your array into a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) so that lookups can be made without scanning the entire array. As such:

```
const lookupMap = new Map(users.map((u) => [u.id, u]));
```

so now you can

```
const user = lookupMap.get(userId)
```

without having to scan all 70000 user objects.

Comment: isn't `users.map` scanning all the array?

Comment: @ikhvjs Yes indeed. The intention is to build the map **once only**. I suspect the OP is repeatedly filtering the array to find individual entries (i.e. the `a` function above is being called multiple times). By building a `Map` up-front, only a single full-scan is required (70000 items should be manageable if performed only once), then subsequent lookups will be lightning fast.

Comment: I think `users.filter` fail to run because exceeding the stack and it would be the same as `users.map`

Comment: @ikhvjs `Array.prototype.filter` won't blow the stack. It might take a long time to complete, but 70000 items? 10 seconds? Easy, even on the oldest of hardware.

Comment: Thanks for helping. Its working as expected.